# Looking for a diff editor for Perforce on Linux, similar to Beyond Compare?

Tags: linux, editor, diff, perforce

I'm looking for a cmd line base diff editor to be used in Linux. It should allow me to edit in VIM mode (can use my VIM shortcuts etc), while at the same time have features like viewing files side-by-side, navigating to previous/next edit etc.

It would be great if it didn't require X server i.e. could use it directly from putty !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That sounds like vimdiff.  I assume you get it with vim because I've never installed it manually.

Comment: Does it have a facility to diff between the Top-of-the-tree and edited versions of a checked out file in perforce ?

Comment: I don't really know how it integrates with perforce directly but it's just like any other diff viewer.

Answer (score 3):

Perforce has the p[4merge](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/products/merge.html) for linux, or you can try [kdiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) (KDE based) or [meld](http://meld.sourceforge.net/) (gnome based). Personally I prefer meld.

Answer (score 1):

Beyond Compare has had a Linux distro for a while.  See: http://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php

Comment: Note that it is implemented using [wine](http://www.winehq.org/) - at least it was when I last tried it about a year ago.